# scrapy list of links from parse result

Tags: scrapy

Here's my current code:

```
#scrap all the cafe links from example.com

    import scrapy, re
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy import Selector

    class DengaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'cafes'
        allowed_domains = ['example.com']
        start_urls = [
            'http://example.com/archives/8136.html',
        ]

        cafeOnlyLink = []

        def parse(self, response):
            cafelink = response.xpath('//li/a[contains(@href, "archives")]/@href').extract()
            twoHourRegex = re.compile(r'^http://example\.com/archives/\d+.html$')
            cafeOnlyLink = [ s for s in cafelink if twoHourRegex.match(s) ]
```

So how should I continue to parse content from each url containing in the [cafeOnlyLink] list? and I want to save all the result from each page in a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
  for url in cafeOnlyLink:
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_save_to_csv)

def parse_save_to_csv(self, response):
  # The content is in response.body, so you have to select what information
  # you want to sent to the csv file.
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been able to create a json file with all the info.